# Nodejs-mongodb: Update document structure for all documents in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection `data` which has around 300k entries and its document looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5xxx85"),
    "user_id" : "1",
    "name" : "test",
    "user_private" : "0"
}
```

now i want to update all the documents in this collection and new document will look like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5xxx85"),
    "rid" : "1",
    "user_name" : "test",
    "is_private" : "private",
    "is_moderator" : "true",
    "amount" : "11111"
}
```

i.e i need to add new fields, update field names and check if `user_private = 0` then put `is_private as private` or else put `is_private as not_private`.

I am a bit new so I am not able to get how can i do this efficiently as entries are around `300k`.
Please suggest some ways, pseudo code will be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a document a filter criteria. Check pseudo code below and follow [link to read more](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany).

You'll need to have an existing value for `user_private`

```
db.messages.updateMany([
  { "user_private" : 0 }, // filter.
  { $set: { 
      "user_private" : "private",
      "is_moderator" : "true"
    } 
  }, // update.
  {
   upsert: true
  }
]);
```

`upserts` - Creates a new document if no documents match the filter or Updates documents that match the filter based on the filter and update parameters provided.

Comment: cool, but what about i need to add new fields and change name of some existing fields as well

Comment: You can perform that as well

Comment: I updated the question, i need to change the name of that specific field too. And also i got to iterate it for all the documents. Its getting really confusing for me.

Comment: You can perform that as well @iamsaksham you need to make use of `$rename` `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/`

Comment: @iamsaksham you can extend akinjide's answer with [Bulk.find.upsert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/), if you want to iterate the queries